# Simple string matching in PHP

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I have a list of filenames and a list of titles which I want to match to each other. (For a TV show tracking application I'm writing)

Example:

```
[Commie] Psycho-Pass 2 - 01 [495A3950].mkv //filename
Psycho-Pass 2 // title it should be matched to

[UTW]_Fate_Kaleid_Liner_Prisma_Ilya_2wei_-_01_[h264-720p][34F564F6].mkv
Fate Kaleid Liner Prisma Ilya 2wei

The.Big.Bang.Theory.S08E05.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION[rartv]
The Big Bang Theory

Modern.Family.S06E03.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[rartv]
Modern Family
```

I find regexp a somewhat tedious solution since the filename format is not always the same. I was thinking of a comparison where the system would decide based on a confidence measurement (percentage threshold). The actual titles are predefined in a database (without episode number). I basically need to match up the filename to a title.

I don't want to go down the route of machine learning if that's not necessary ;)

Any ideas?

Comment: you could try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Can you provide some real examples? I don't think you are giving away much about your app if you post 5-6 actual string you want to match. And, regex is probably you most likely scenario. Just warming you up to that.

Comment: PHP, being an interpreter, by definition isn't fast.  Your best bet is to lean on the regex stuff, which I think is implemented in C; it might actually be fast by itself.

Comment: Running speed is not really an issue. With fast I actually meant easy and fast to write. It just has to match a couple titles a day

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following simple method work?

```
for each $title
    $count = 0
    for each $word in $title
        if $word in $filename:
            $count++

    /* additive error */
    if count >= (number of words in title) - $some_alpha:
        /* found matching title */

    /* multiplicative error */
    if count / (number of words in title) >= $some_percentage:
        /* found matching title */
```

Or are you looking for something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I stumbled upon the `levenshtein` php method:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Since I already have the database populated with the Show names and I just want to match the filename, I can use that method to iterate over each show name and pick the best fit!

Answer (score 0):

According to your text, you have a database with a list of titles already stored. Now you want to match them with file_names. Below, I have the code that will do that. I have used match and does not match in places where you would put the things to do if they matched.

The first thing you have to do is clean your file name and then match the titles with your file name. In this case, I will just say your are trying to match titles with file name from you r list called [Commie] Psycho-Pass 2 - 01 [495A3950].mkv. The code is show below. You can copy and paste and it will work.

```
/** list of titles from the database**/ 
$title_array = ["Psycho-Pass 2", "Fate Kaleid Liner Prisma Ilya 2wei", "The Big Bang Theory", "Modern Family"];

/** filename you want to match with the titles **/
$filename_raw = "[Commie] Psycho-Pass 2 - 01 [495A3950].mkv";

/**
 * Clean the $filename
 * Replace the dot and underscore with space, and remember to escape the characters, because they are special
 * Here we just have a variable holding the pattern we need to replace and the replacement
 **/ 
$patterns = array ('/\./','/\_/');
$replace = array (' ', ' ');
/** 
 * this is were replacement occurs
 **/
$filename_clean = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $filename_raw);

foreach($title_array as $title){
    if (strpos($filename_clean,$title) !== false) {
        echo "Match <br />";
        /**
         * you might want to put a break here since your have already found the match but I will leave that up to you
         */
    }else{
        echo "Match Not found<br />";
    }
}
```